# azure AD B2C starter pack, for edit profile custom policy,if the user is signed in, authentication is skipped, how to force the user to authenticate?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

this is the journey

```
<UserJourney Id="ProfileEdit">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

this is the link
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/main/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the starter pack, the single sign-on behaviour is not configured.
By default it uses "Tenant" scope: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior.

This means the single sign-on session is active in the ProfileEdit policy.
You can configure it to be Policy scoped in ProfileEdit policy:

```xml
<!-- inside RelyingParty element, under DefaultUserJourney -->
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Policy" />
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

You could also set it to Suppressed to disable single sign-on in the ProfileEdit policy.

Comment: thank u so much! works! saved me lots of time